# private_pub "incorrect signature" issue in production

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, faye, private-pub

I am using private_pub gem to achieve real time chat in my app. Now while this works perfectly fine on staging, I am unable to get it working on production. Both servers are Amazon Ec2 instances with Ubuntu OS.

In production I get an error when I hit the page containing `subscribe_to` method. Though faye.js is being served fine.

The error in browser console is : `"error":"Incorrect signature."`

I have also added `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production` as suggested in one of the issues.

Both production and staging have exactly same apache config and ports open, with an exception being staging uses ufw firewall. Anything additional that needs to be done?

I am using this proxypass settings in httpd conf in apache.

```
ProxyPass "/faye/"  "ws://127.0.0.1:9292/"
ProxyPass "/faye/"  "http://127.0.0.1:9292/faye/"
```

Also, there are no errors in apache and application logs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the same config for both faye server and private pub gem. Try restarting the faye server and check it again.

"Incorrect signature" has nothing to do with apache proxy.